# How to define a method with yield in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'v read a article about a block and `Proc` and `yield`, but I don't get it yet.
To understand `yield` I tried to write a method `find_map`, that returns array, except for that it works like `find_each`.

But I couldn't figure out how to handle `yield` to enable the function.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.find_map
        array = []
        find_each
            # TODO: push each result to `array`
            yield
        end
        array
    end
end
```

How can I write a method like this?

Comment: If you found either answer helpful, don't forget to choose one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yield` statement executes the block, which is passed as an argument to a method:

```
def my_method
  if block_given? # checks if block is passed to the method
    yield
  end
end

my_method{ puts 'Method to execute' }
#=> Method to execute
```

To modify an object you need to pass that object as argument to `yield` for example:

```
class Array
  def self.find_map
    array = []
    yield(array)
    array
  end
end
p Array.find_map{|arr| arr << 's' << 't' } #=> ["s", "t"]
```

You have `find_map` as a class method which can be called as: `ActiveRecord::Base.find_map`, by looking at your code expecting `find_each` to be class method(which expects an option), too. The workaround would be something like this:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_map
    array = []
    find_each(*yield(array))
    array
  end
end
```

So:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.find_map{|arr| arr << {:conditions => "age > 21"} }
```

will insert `{:conditions => "age > 21"}` in to `array` defined inside `find_map` when block is being executed and passed as  `{:conditions => "age > 21"}` into `find_each` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for late reply. Your answer are very helpful for me, but I wonder is there no way to implement a method that returns a `Array` without inserting to a variable like `Array#map"?

Comment: I didn't understand what you're trying to say. What did you mean by *there no way to implement a method that returns a `Array` without inserting to a variable like `Array#map"`*?

Comment: I want to have a method that returns Array of `ActiveRecord::Base` class by `ActiveRecord::Base.find_map{|u| u }`.

Comment: @Tetsu : If I understand you correctly, you want `ActiveRecord::Relation` object when you call that method, right? That won't as straight as you think it'd be then. Take a look at how these [query methods](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb) are implemented if you're looking to achieve that. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for info. It seems to be too much difficult for me now. Maybe I'll try this someday.

Answer (score 0):

```
   class MyCollection 
     include Enumerable
     def initialize( someItems )
       @items = someItems
     end
     def each
       @items.each{ |i| 
         yield( i )
       }
     end
   end
```

Here you initialize a MyCollection object with an array, which will be
stored in the instance variable, @items . When you call one of the methods
provided by the Enumerable module (such as min , max , or collect ), this will call
the each method to obtain each piece of data one at a time. So, here the
each method passes each value from the @items array into the block where
that item is assigned to the block parameter i . The keyword yield is a special bit of Ruby magic that runs a block of code that was passed to the each method.
(I found it in The book of ruby)